# finding nested object value in java script

Tags: javascript, json

JSON file from URL

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "actions": ["OUTPUT:2" ],
      "idle_timeout": 0,
      "cookie": 0,
      "packet_count": 2,
      "hard_timeout": 0
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
  //alert("INTo function");
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/flow",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#flow").append(data["1"].actions.OUTPUT[i]);  
      $("#flow").append(data["1"].idle_timeout);
      $("#flow").append(data["1"].cookie);
      $("#flow").append(data["1"].packet_count);
      $("#flow").append(data["1"].hard_timeout);              
    }
  });
}
```

This is the JavaScript code which I have used it, to find values of the object inside the nested JSON response coming from a URL.

Comment: What is exact question ? what is desired output ?

Comment: *this is the java code which i had used to find values*, it's JavaScript and sure, so what's the question?

Comment: This is not Java code.  And you have not actually asked a question.

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript...

Answer (score 1):

Your sample does not look like valid json. Since the value of "1" is an array, you should try to access it via the index.  e.g.`$("#flow").append(data["1"][0].idle_timeout)`

Answer (score 0):

The code used to find the values inside the nested JSON object is actually incorrect.

You must use `data["1"][0].actions[0].OUTPUT` to retrieve the value 2.